# Modelling friction and its application to generalised forces in the Euler Lagrange equations in a 2D Unicycle model

Tags: applied-mechanics, torque, modeling, friction

I am in progress of building a simplistic 2D model of an electric unicycle with the intention of creating a stabilizing controller. The EUC can be modeled as an elaborate inverted pendulum and the full model is included below.
The control inputs of the system are $u = \tau_{motor}$, and the generalised coordinates are $q = (\theta, \phi)^T$.
[image]

The system is to be solved using the Euler-Lagrange equations of the 2nd form and the generalised coordinates;
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} = Q
\end{equation}
Where L is the Lagrangian, defined as $L=T-U$; for $T$ being the total kinetic energy of the system, $U$ the total potential energy and $q = (\theta, \phi, \psi, l_{rider}$ being the (vectorised) generalised coordinates.
$Q$ is the generalised forces of the system, and is theoretically derived from the principle of virtual work. It is defined as such;
$$ Q = \sum_{i=1}^{n} F_{i} \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial \dot{q}} \equiv \sum_{i=1}^{n} \tau_{i} \frac{\partial \omega_i}{\partial \dot{q}} $$

*Foreword* The EUC is modeled on an electric design, roughly emulating the design shown in this video, [how an electric unicycle works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OTtymYnFB0&t=244s). Essentially the motor powers some coils that creates a repulsive electromagnetic force that propels some very strong magnets that are part of the wheel causing rotational motion.
In my model, for the interest of simplicity, I will consider the motor and the chassis to be rigidly connected in such a way that one could not rotate about the other. This gives the system 2 degrees of freedom as opposed to 3.
*The below cross sectional diagram of the EUC illustrates this point visually - a rotation in A results in an equal rotation in C.*
[image]

**1.** For each rotating part are there 2 coefficients of friction and therefore two fricitional forces present, or is there just one frictional force that due to $Newton's \ 3^{rd} \ Law$ ("Every action has an equal and opposite reaction") will act on both the rotating parts?
*Put differently:* None of the angularly moving parts can be considered 'static' in the sense that the surface that a sliding block moves upon is static.
In the case for the motor and wheel, both the wheel could be sliding across the motor (causing the unicycle to roll forwards) or the motor could be sliding across the wheel (causing the chassis to tilt).
Does this imply that there will be two frictional forces generated for every angular motion in this system, each with it's own coefficient of friction?

**2.** In the case of air resistance, which has a well defined formula for laminar flow;
$$ F_D = \frac{1}{2} v^2 C_D A $$
Would it be physically meaningful to apply the cross sectional area of a 3D model to this 2D formulation of the problem, or should I apply the 2D cross sectional area (i.e. the length of the EUC from point of contact to top of the chassis)?
I am asking this because I intend to apply the 2D control law to a 3D model and assume no yaw motion and also assume roll stability to be the responsibility of the rider (thus making the 2D model applicable in 3D space).

Thanks for your help.
*Tags* Friction, Modeling, Torque, Applied-Mechanics.

========================

*Here are two cheeky questions which I realise are beyond the scope of this help resource*

*1.* Some clarification on applying the frictional forces as generalised coordinates would be nice as I am used to applying generalised forces to forces and not to torques.
As an example, if I were to consider the friction torque acting against the movement of the motor w.r.t the wheel, $\tau_{motor_{Fr}} = -\mu_{motor} \cdot (\dot{\phi} - \dot{\theta})$, would the generalised torque be calculated as such :
$$ -\mu_{motor} (\dot{\phi} - \dot{\theta}) \cdot \frac{ \partial{(\dot{\theta} - \dot{\phi})} }{\partial{\dot{q}}} = \mu_{motor} (\dot{\theta} - \dot{\phi}) \cdot (1,-1)^T $$
My thinking is as follows:
According to the formula for $Q$, where the $i^{th}$ particle is the motor; the movement of the motor that causes work to be done is $\omega_{motor} = \phi - \theta$. And so inputting the $\omega$ and $\tau$ as defined we would get the above formula.
Is this correct?

*2.* In case I have caught the attention of anyone proficient in friction modelling, some recommended mathematical models would be nice (one's that a numerical solver could solve for without too much stiffness issues), but that would be a bonus.

Comment: It won't move very far without friction.